# Ubuntu 14.04- Force lower resolution on Macbook Retina Display

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, nvidia-graphics-card, macbook-pro-retina

I am dual-booting Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro Retina Display. I have also installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers. Everything works fine, but the problem is that since the screen is such a high resolution, everything is tiny (text, icons, menus, everything). I want to set the display to a lower resolution using the system settings > Displays, but the drop-down menu for 'Resolution' only contains one option: 2880x1800. Before I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers, I was able to select a lower resolution her.

I apologize in advance, because I do not know what specific information I need to provide. I am very new to Linux, and frankly have no idea what I'm doing.

P.S. I know that there's other ways to solve this problem, namely by tweaking various settings to scale up text, icons, window sizes, etc. individually, but frankly that just sounds like a huge hassle. I'd much rather be able to change the screen resolution so that everything scales uniformly.

Answer (score 1):

I have realized that I made a pretty stupid mistake. Rather than trying to change the resolution in System Settings > Displays, I had to run the nvidia-settings command, which let me choose a different resolution.